# #VALUE ERROR from my VBA function

Tags: vba, excel

So I wrote a simple function in VBA and I want to use it in my excel workbook. I wrote the following code:

```
Option Explicit
Public Function KOLICINA(fiksnacena As Long, ceni() As Long, nedela() As Long) As Long
    Dim brojac As Integer
    For brojac = 1 To UBound(nedela)
        If Not ((IsEmpty(nedela(brojac) Or nedela(brojac) = 0) And ceni(brojac) <>  fiksnacena)) Then KOLICINA = nedela(brojac)
    Next brojac
End Function
```

When I try to use it in a worksheet cell (using `=KOLICINA(18;G22:G26;H22:H26)`)
, I get the `#VALUE` error.
I don't understand why. The function should go through `nedela` Array and if it finds a Non empty or different value than `0` AND if the matching cell in the `ceni` Array is different from the number `fiksnacena`, it should return the value of the cell in `nedela`.

Comment: Maybe change `ceni()` and `nedela()` to `Range` instead of `Long`?

Comment: `Then KOLICINA = nedela(brojac)` could perhaps be replaced by `Then` followed by  `KOLICINA = nedela(brojac)` followed by `Exit Function` followed by `End If`. Once you find the return value, why continue the loop (unless you want the last match)?

Comment: Apparently you meant `If Not (IsEmpty(nedela(brojac)) Or nedela(brojac) = 0) And ceni(brojac) <>  fiksnacena Then`.

Comment: @JohnColeman Yes it could, I tried it but still the #VALUE error is shown...

Comment: @GSerg Yes that's what I meant, but still doesn't solve the problem with #VALUE.

Comment: @TheGuyThatDoesn'tKnowMuch I have tried that before, doesn't solve the problem.

Comment: There is no such thing as an `Empty` long, so I don't see the point of the `isEmpty` test on the elements of an array of longs

Answer (score 3):

You cannot simply pass a cell range reference into a UDF and have it interpreted as a single dimensioned array of longs.

```
Public Function KOLICINA(fiksnacena As Long, ceni As Range, nedela As Range) As Long
    Dim brojac As Long, vCeni As Variant, vNedela As Variant
    vCeni = ceni.Value2
    vNedela = nedela.Value2
    For brojac = LBound(vNedela, 1) To UBound(vNedela, 1)
        If Not ((IsEmpty(vNedela(brojac, 1) Or vNedela(brojac, 1) = 0) And vCeni(brojac, 1) <> fiksnacena)) Then
            KOLICINA = vNedela(brojac, 1)
            Exit For
        End If
    Next brojac
End Function
```

When you dump values from a range reference into an array, you always end up with a two dimensioned array; in your example it is 1 to 5, 1 to 1.

To further illustrate this point, your original UDF code would work if you pulled the values from the ranges after transposing them and finish off the UDF with CSE so that the values are processed as an array.

```
=KOLICINA(18, VALUE(TRANSPOSE(G22:G26)), VALUE(TRANSPOSE(H22:H26)))
```

Finalize with [ctrl]+[shift]+[enter].

Comment: Thank you all, @Jeeped especially, your answer solved my problem. beginner's mistake